# Invalid token - firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have encounter an issue when I want to deploy my web apps on Vercel. I am developing an apps that has login function. At local environment, everything is good, login/logout function works well but when I deploy to Vercel, it show errors

```
The token is invalid: file_put_contents(/var/task/user/storage/framework/cache/data/24/fc/24fc69d48eaa682f929a7045e8f4700237c0083e): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I also had add the web app to authorized domain.

Here is my code at verify the token:

```
try {
                $signInResult = $auth->signInWithEmailAndPassword($request->email, $request->password);
                $idTokenString = $signInResult->idToken();

                try {
                    /** @var \Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Plain $verifiedIdToken */
                    $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);

                    $uid = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub');

                    $_SESSION['displayName'] = $signInResult->data()["displayName"];
                    $_SESSION['verified_user_id'] = $uid;
                    $_SESSION['idTokenString'] = $idTokenString;

                    $_SESSION['status'] = "Logged in successfully";

                    return redirect()->route('userHome');
                } catch (InvalidToken $e) {
                    echo 'The token is invalid: ' . $e->getMessage();
                } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                    echo 'The token could not be parsed: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error normally happens when the folder the resource is trying to save in or read does not exist. ensure you are creating the folder path structure to that location before you save the credentials to it and if the folder does not exist, you should handle it within your app as file streams a potential point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Create session cookie
Given an ID token sent to your server application from a client application, you can convert it to a session cookie:

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth\CreateSessionCookie\FailedToCreateSessionCookie;

$idToken = '...';

// The TTL must be between 5 minutes and 2 weeks and can be provided as
// an integer value in seconds or a DateInterval

$fiveMinutes = 300;
$oneWeek = new \DateInterval('P7D');

try {
    $sessionCookieString = $auth->createSessionCookie($idToken, $oneWeek);
} catch (FailedToCreateSessionCookie $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Maintain your user auth flow with COOKIES

**Verify a Firebase Session Cookie**

```
Use Auth::verifySessionCookie() to verify a Session Cookie:

use Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\FailedToVerifySessionCookie;

$sessionCookieString = '...';

try {
    $verifiedSessionCookie = $auth->verifySessionCookie($sessionCookieString);
} catch (FailedToVerifySessionCookie $e) {
    echo 'The Session Cookie is invalid: '.$e->getMessage();
}

$uid = $verifiedSessionCookie->claims()->get('sub');

$user = $auth->getUser($uid);
```